# Is it considered a good practice to put a redirection method into another one?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

For example, if you have to redirect in almost every controller, is it a good practice to put that into another method and use it from there?

E.g. There's always this line of code:

return Redirect::route($route)->with('err_msg', 'Some error');

Is it better to put that into, let's say, and AdminController and call it from there passing only the error message and the route you want it to be redirected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't really make a difference since you will just be calling a "helper" function and then in that function you will still be calling the `Redirect` each time.

Let's say you create:

```
function redirect_user($route,$error_msg)
{
    return Redirect::route($route)->with('err_msg', $error_msg);
}
```

Unless you want the helper to do something else (like validate the `$route`, format/log the `error`) in a generic way particular to your application's needs, there is no real need to complicate things by introducing an extra `function()` call doing practically nothing more than wrapping the `redirect`

Comment: I'd like to log some info as well. Thank you very much for your answer.